# Remove value from front of queue in C

Tags: c, queue

I'm trying to use this function to remove a value from the front of a queue. It seems to work the first time (though I might be wrong about this) but when freeing a node the second time it triggers a breakpoint which crashes the program. How do I fix this?

```
printf("Value removed = %d\n", dequeue(myQueue));

int dequeue(queue q)
{
    if (q == NULL || q->head == NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    node * head = q->head;
    node * temp = head;

    if (temp == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }

    int returnValue = head->value;

    //Free first node in queue
    head = temp->next;
    free(temp);

    //Return value that was removed
    return returnValue;
}
```

Comment: You forgot to update q->head

Comment: Cheers. It's all good now. :)

Comment: show your queue structure ?

Comment: btw temp is head so `if (temp == NULL){ return; }` not needed.

Comment: Please post the definition of `queue`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You updates a local variable, instead  updating `head`   in your queue structure `q`:

```
head = temp->next;  // this is local variable
```

should be:

```
q->head = temp->next;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems that he is passing the struct by value, so this solves nothing. The program design is fundamentally broken.

Comment: @Lundin No he is passing address of structure that is `q` in function and I am suggesting to update `q->head` that will reflect change any ways(code doesn't change `q` itself)

Comment: There is nothing in the code indicating that he is passing by pointer. I suppose he could be using a typedef to hide the pointer, but then the program design would still be fundamentally broken... just in another way.

Answer (score 0):

Pass back the updated queue so that it reflects in main function also where your calling. or you will changing only local structure which will be poppedof the stack once the function call is over

```
myQueue = dequeue(myQueue));


int dequeue(queue q)
{
if (q == NULL || q->head == NULL)
{
    return NULL;
}

node * temp = q->head; 

printf("Value removed = %d\n",head->value);

//Free first node in queue
q->head = temp->next;  
free(temp);

return q->head;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Have you typedef'd `queue` as a pointer? That's very bad style, don't do it, ever! It makes the code completely unreadable.

Otherwise, if you haven't done that, you should never pass a struct by value either. If you have done that, you need to re-design the whole program so that it uses pointers. All functions should be along the lines of `int dequeue(queue* q)`.

In either of the above cases, you need to step back and re-define the whole linked list ADT to something that makes sense.

Furthermore, that alone won't help because you are only working with local variables inside the dequeue function. As others have shown, you must alter the actual linked list as well.